# how to display text to 8x8 matrix with 64-bit long integers?

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, display, led-matrix

I have an array of 64-bit integers to display on an 8x8 led matrix

```
const int LEN1 = sizeof(Hours);
const uint64_t Hours[] = {
  0x00043c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x000c3c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x001c3c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x0000001818000000,
  0x0000001818100000,
  0x0000001818180000,
  0x00000018181c0000,
  0x000000181c1c0000,
  0x0000001c1c1c0000,
  0x0000041c1c1c0000,
  0x00000c1c1c1c0000
};
```

and here I have a loop to display it:

```
void displayImage(uint64_t image) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    byte row = (image >> i * 8) & 0xFF;
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      lc.setLed(0, i, j, bitRead(row, j));
    }
  }
}
```

but I can't use a loop in this way and I'm not proficient in byte shifting principles too.

can you please explain how the loop above works or help me to write this loop as

```
const int LEN1 = sizeof(Hours);

void displayImage(Hours[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < LEN1; i++) {
    //display Hours
    }
}
```

Comment: it is about displaying text on 8x8 led matrix using arduino/

Comment: its not really about loops in c++,  what would be helpful is more detail about the hardware, platform, and the libraries in use. Data-types and libraries seem to be the main issues here.

Comment: @jsotola, it is an Arduino question. it is about the use of Arduino's `Print.print(num, HEX)` function which doesn't have a version for uint64_t type so it must be replaced with at least two prints and the leading 0 must by handled

Comment: @Juraj i am probably missing something then ... i see no Serial.print code in OP's listing ... deleted my comments

Comment: @jsotola, sorry, some display libraries implement base class Print and the Answer by j0h confused me to think it is the case in this Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, well there are some things I don't know about your code, and hardware, like if the LCD library can handle uint64_t datatypes. I know the Serial.print() function can only handle up to a unit32_t, so I'm using that.

I think your length variable might not be the right length, you might want to add in a check for that in your code. Much of the Arduino code is 8 bit.

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
uint32_t b = 0x0;

const uint64_t Hours[] = {
  0x00043c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x000c3c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x001c3c3c3c3c3c00,
  0x0000001818000000,
  0x0000001818100000,
  0x0000001818180000,
  0x00000018181c0000,
  0x000000181c1c0000,
  0x0000001c1c1c0000,
  0x0000041c1c1c0000,
  0x00000c1c1c1c0000
};

//const int LEN1 = sizeof(Hours[0]);
const int LEN1 = sizeof(Hours)/sizeof(uint64_t);
       Serial.print("Length: ");
       Serial.println(LEN1);
 
   for (int i = 0; i < LEN1; i++) {
       b=Hours[i]>>16;
       Serial.println(b,HEX);
       }
}

void loop() {
}
```

I think this code will do what you want, at least as I understand it.
beware of what data-types your LCD library can handle.

Comment: welp, I see where I borked this code, but im tired and huingry, and gotta go home. But I still think this will put you close to where you want to be